# Slicer data source connection in Excel 2013

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2013

The issue is that I have various chart connected to various Slicers, but now i need to change the data connection of those chart. Once i change the data connection of the charts the slicer can't recognize the charts. Is it possible to change a slicer data source connection in Excel 2013 without deleting and creating the slicer all over again?

Answer (score 0):

I use slicers frequently, on multiple Pivot tables. Sometimes after editing a table, I can't see the same number of Pivot tables available in Report Connections. Sounds similar to what you experience.
I learned that if you change the source area for one Pivot, you must change the source area for the other(s) as well. Same sheet, same start coordinate and same end coordinate.

Hope that helped.